# Always print to default printer even the printervname is specified

Tags: c#, printing

I created one windows application in which I need to print PDF files silently.

```
string printername="jn-01";

        if (printername != "NULL")
        {
            using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
            {
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printername;
                MessageBox.Show(printername);

                pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
                if (pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(e.FullPath);
                    info.Verb = "PrintTo";
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    Process.Start(info);
                }
            }
```

I use above code for printing. But the system always print to default ptinter.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the printer name on a print dialog, but you aren't using the print dialog to print. Notice how you never use `pd` when printing. You are instead executing the PDF file (effectively using `ShellExecute`) with `PrintTo` verb. Now `PrintTo` verb supports providing the printer name as a command line argument. You can set it on `info.Arguments`. However for this to work, the default application that handles the PDF files needs to support it. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776883.aspx) for more info on these verbs.

If the default PDF application has no support for this, then your alternative could be to call [SetDefaultPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before printing and then restore it to its previous value after printing (Use [GetDefaultPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find which one is default first). Note that this changes the default printer for the user, so should not be the default choice when doing this.